# How do I alter this code to only show the output once in PHP?

Tags: php, preg-replace

Basically I have a code that when you type in a word which is listed in the array it replaced it at randomly from one of the words from another array. In this case I want to make it so words in **$bye** are replaced by words from $hello and words from **$animal** are replaced at random by words from **$colour**.

This all works fine though what I want to know is how would I go about making it so that in the echo it does not display it twice and just combine it.

For example, if I typed in **"bye my cat"** it would give me for example **"hi my red"** instead of what it currently gives which is **"yo my catbye my red"**.

Here is my current code:

```
$hello=array('hello', 'hi', 'yo');  //$replacements
shuffle($hello);

$animal = array('/mouse/', '/cat/', '/dog/'); //pattern

$colour = array('yellow', 'blue', 'red');  //$replacements
shuffle($dog);

echo preg_replace($bye, $hello, $words);
echo preg_replace($mouse, $dog, $words);
?>
```

Comment: your current code is confusing, you use the variables $dog, $bye and  $words without defining them but don't use $animal and $colour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo preg_replace($mouse, $dog, preg_replace($bye, $hello, $words));
```

You can just combine them..

Or assign the result of first replacement back to `$words`, then do the second

```
$words =  preg_replace($bye, $hello, $words);
echo preg_replace($mouse, $dog, $words);
```

Comment: which is the same as: `preg_replace(array($mouse, $bye), array($dog,  $hello), $words)`

Answer (score 0):

May be need add

```
echo '<br>';
```

after first preg_replace?
Even instead of preg_replace here fit str_replace

Answer (score 0):

I modified your code a little....it's a matter of concepts:

```
<?php
$words= "bye my cat";
echo $words."</br>";

$hello=array('hello', 'hi', 'yo');  //$replacements
shuffle($hello);

$pattern = array('/bye/', '/cat/', '/dog/'); //pattern

$replacements = array('hello', 'red', 'blue');  //$replacements


echo preg_replace($pattern, $replacements, $words);

?>
```

I hope you'll be clear XD

PS: The output is fine.

Saludos.